# Execute SQL from within an Azure Data Studio extension?

Tags: vscode-extensions, azure-data-studio

I want to create an extension for `Azure Data Studio` that accesses a database. The database (SQL Server) is already available in `Azure Data Studio`, as I am manually interacting with it.

Reading the [Extensible API documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/azure-data-studio/extensibility-apis?view=sql-server-ver15) it seems to be possible to access the databases available in `Azure Data Studio`. But how do I send SQL queries and receive their replies from within my extension code? What would be the SQL client for my extension code?

Answer (score 3):

I found no docs about this, however, I found myself this piece of code that works.

I don't know if this is a correct approach.

```js
var connection = await azdata.connection.getCurrentConnection();

if (connection) {
    var uri = await azdata.connection.getUriForConnection(connection.connectionId);
    var g = azdata.dataprotocol.getProvidersByType(
        azdata.DataProviderType.QueryProvider
    )[0] as QueryProvider;
    var t = await g.runQueryAndReturn(
        uri,
        "SELECT TOP 1 * FROM sys.objects"
    );
    var jj = t.rows[0][0];

    vscode.window.showInformationMessage(jj.displayValue);
}
```